# Video autoplay doesn't work on all iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, video, autoplay

On the top of this [homepage](http://www.nevada-club.com/), I have a video with muted, autoplay and playsinline attributes.

The video is autoplaying on desktop & mobile I've tested (Chrome, Safari, Firefox).
Surprisingly, the video is not playing for lots of iPhone users, they have a PLAY button showing, requiring interaction then.

Here is my code :

```
<video id="vid" width="100%" height="auto" preload="auto" autoplay muted playsinline>
  <source src="http://www.nevada-club.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Nevada_Club.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://www.nevada-club.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Nevada_Club.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="http://www.nevada-club.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Nevada_Club.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>

<script>
     var herovide = document.getElementById('vid');
       herovide.autoplay=true;
       herovide.load();  
</script>
```

Does someone knows why some people have this issue and how to fix it ?
Somebody who has this issue was on iOS 11.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

If iPhone is in battery save mode it will not autoplay videos. Otherwise it should play with your code.

Also i don't think you need any js to autoplay.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, the only screenshot I got from somebody, shows that he was on Battery Save Mode (yellow battery icon). That might be the thing, thanks a lot !

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You have no idea how much time and pain you have saved me.