# when <video> src is changed, video doesn't auto play on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, video, html5-video

I have some code to change the src attr of a video on mobile. It looks like this:

```
<div class="product-video--mobile swiper-slide">
   <video class="product-video"
     src="{{ variant.metafields.Details.videoMobileURL }}"
     width="100%"
     type="video/mp4"
     loop muted playsinline autoplay
     data-video-src="{{ variant.metafields.Details.videoMobileURL }}"
     alt="product-video"></video>
</div>
```

JS:

`$(".product-video--mobile .product-video").attr("src", $(".active-video").data("mobile-video-variant"));`

On desktop, this code seems to work fine but on iOS, it stops playing.

Per these answers:

[Video autoplay doesn't work on all iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226793/video-autoplay-doesnt-work-on-all-iphone)

[HTML5 Video autoplay on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570460/html5-video-autoplay-on-iphone)

[HTML5 Video Background not playing Safari on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325257/html5-video-background-not-playing-safari-on-iphone)

I have both `playsinline` and `muted` attributes on my video tag, but it still won't autoplay. Is it because I changed the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`play()`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp) method in JS.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.play();
```

Comment: Interesting. I was under the impression those parameters just worked. But I guess if the src changes you gotta reboot it

Comment: Whether those parameters work or not is very browser-specific, and sometimes battery-saving-mode on mobile changes things too.