# Video not autoplaying in IOS

Tags: html, ios, video

I am trying to figure out why the video is not autoplaying in IOS devices?

```
<div class="video-container">
<video id="intro-video" video-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" poster="" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source video-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" video-width="1600" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source video-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" video-width="900" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source video-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" video-width="480" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
</video>
```

`Playsinline` is already added as described in the IOS video documentation

`webkit-playsinline` is not added

Comment: have you check battery save mode / low power mode in your IPhone? If it's on the autoplay wouldn't work.

Comment: No that's not the issue

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226793/video-autoplay-doesnt-work-on-all-iphone

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968386/autoplay-video-html-on-safari-ios-14-2

Answer (score -1):

Most modern web-browsers don't allow to auto-play audio and video if there is no interaction from the user, as a click on the webpage.